# What was the original purpose of C strncpy() function?

Tags: c, history, standard-library

C standard library has [`strncpy` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy), declared as:

```
char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
```

It's a strange beast, as it *fills* `n` bytes of memory pointed to by `dest`. It does this by first copying from string `src` as much as it can (either `n` bytes copied or end of `src` reached), then if `n` bytes isn't full yet, it fills the rest with 0 bytes.

So, it wipes the entire `dest` overwriting any old data or uninitialized garbage there. Also, it does not necessarily produce a string in `dest`, because if `strlen(src)` is equal or longer than `n`, no terminating 0 byte is written. So, for copying NUL-terminated strings, it often does extra work with the 0 padding, unlike other string functions. And then it requires extra code to ensure result is a string (such as `strncpy(dst, src, 10); dst[10]=0;`). So it looks as if it was not designed for simply copying C strings at all.

**What was the original purpose of `strncpy` function? Why does work the way it does?**

---

I have two speculations, which I'll list here just as an example of what kind of confirmed answer I'm hoping to get:

- Maybe some earlier language back then had diffrent kind of strings (such as with length prefix), and for them `strncpy` worked somehow more logically as a string copy. Then Maybe C copied the function without altering behavior to account for terminating NUL.
- Maybe at that time, before appearance of all the modern database alternatives, it was common to have binary data files with fixed size records, where C structs were accessed with `fseek`, followed by `fwrite`/`fread`. When setting fixed size string in such a struct, you'd want any garbage overwritten with 0, and you wouldn't want to waste precious storage space by always having one extra zero.

I don't know where an answer could be found, but perhaps some old reference manuals or textbooks from 1960's or 1970's might discuss the intended use.

Comment: Could you help us understand what you find so strange about this? The 0-initialization that `strncpy` does over `strcpy` is great. To not do so would be a "short write vulnerability" See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/BufferOverflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002577-SW18 for details

Comment: The fact that it creates a not-a-c-string when the buffer is not large enough makes it unusable. The fact that copying long utf-8 can result in illegal utf-8 is equally bad.

Comment: @gnasher729: The purpose of `strncopy` is to convert from a C-style string to a fixed-length record. In other words: the fact that the result isn't a C-style string is *the whole point* of this function in the first place. The same reason applies to your second criticism: if you convert a C-style string contain UTF-8 to a fixed-length record, there is no guarantee that the record boundary lines up with a character boundary (or a grapheme cluster boundary or a glyph boundary or any other kind of text boundary). Besides, `strncopy` predates UTF-8 by well over a decade, so making `strncopy` aware

Comment: … of UTF-8 would have required prescience and/or time travel.

Comment: @Alexander Well, `strncpy` semantics are very different from all other "str" functions (including `*scanf` and `fgets`), don't you agree? Was short write vulnerability something that people were concerned about at the time `strncpy` was designed?

Comment: Also, I'd like to explicitly state that this is not meant as any kind of criticism of `strncpy`, so please no arguing if `strncpy` is good or bad or ugly. It's different, which I hope I have sufficiently demonstrated in my question text, and I am asking, why is it different?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate

Comment: Although unfortunately the accepted answer is poor, and you should probably look at this one instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1454071/212858

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good source for answering design questions regarding C is the rationale document published by X3J11, the ANSI technical committee that first standardized the C language: "Rationale for the ANSI C Programming Language", Silicon Press 1990. Here we find:

> 4.11.2.4 The `strncpy` function
> `strncpy` was initially introduced into the C library to deal with fixed-length name fields in structures such as directory entries. Such fields are not used in the same way as strings: the trailing null is unnecessary for a maximum-length field, and setting trailing bytes for shorter names to null assures efficient field-wise comparisons. `strncpy` is not by origin a "bounded `strcpy`," and the Committee has preferred to recognize existing practice rather than alter the function to better suit it to such use.

Fun fact from my brief time looking at optimizations for high-performance *business computing* in the early 2000s: In many real-life use cases of `strncpy` the typical length of the source string is significantly shorter than the width of the destination field, yet many implementations of `strncpy` did not optimize the zero-fill portion of its functionality, using a simple loop zeroing one byte at a time. As I recall I prepared an assembly-language level implementation for Solaris that included this missing optimization. I see that the OpenSolaris repository includes what looks very much like [my code](https://github.com/kofemann/opensolaris/blob/master/usr/src/lib/libc/sparc/gen/strncpy.s).

Comment: Excellent quote, just what I was after!

Answer (score 3):

I can answer definitively, since I wrote the originals ~1977, having moved from BTL Piscataway to Murray Hill.
They were first named `str*n`, but were later renamed `strn*`, as there was some system in BTL that needed first 6 letters of external names to be unique.

I was working on kernel & user code that supported rudimentary per-process accounting, which started with someone else, but needed extensions due to big increase in UNIX systems in computer centers, who wanted more performance analysis.
I.e. this was supported by commands like accton(1), acctcms(1),acctcom(1), acctmerge(1) (all in UNIX/TS 1.0, Nov 1978, which was ~Research V7 with first steps of PWB/UNIX influence. Think of that as 1.0, then PWB/UNIX 2.0, then UNIX System III...

The records described in acct(5) held the last 8 characters of the command pathname,truncated if necessary and thus possibly not null-terminated.
I found multiple instances of inline code to manipulate these, which seemed a bad idea, so I wrote the `str*n` functions and replaced the inline code, and also used them in the various commands.

**I also thought it was a good idea for better code safety.:-)** Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe at that time, before appearance of all the modern database alternatives, it was common to have binary data files with fixed size records

It's *still* common to have binary data formats with fixed-size records in low-level code. Many protocols designed mainly for fast (de-)serialization do exactly this.

And I still, when implementing those protocols, find myself using `strncpy` if they're null-padded, or writing an equivalent generalization if they're space-padded instead.

So, I think you've correctly understood the use case, and you're just mistaken in believing that use case no longer applies because you happen to be working at a higher level of abstraction.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply, that the use case has disappeared (though I'd say it's more robust to first zero an entire struct instead of individual fields), but rather wonder if that was the _original_ purpose of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say one needs to store a large amount of short strings in some preallocated array or buffer, all of the same maximum length N. Using a classic C string will require to reserve N+1 bytes per string. But by using the knowledge about the maximum length, one can obviously save one byte per string in the array (strings of length  smaller than N get `\0` at the end, strings of length N not).

Copying a standard C string into such a buffer is exactly what `strncopy` does (with the extra bonus of zero padding all unused bytes).

Are there many use cases for short strings with a maximum length? **Absolutely, even today!** Not just for filenames in old operating systems (like [Raymond Chen mentioned here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050107-00/?p=36773) as a use case for `strncpy` in Unix System V, or [gnasher729](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/438027) mentioned about MS DOS). Out of my head:

- operating systems or databases with user names allowing a certain maximum length (for example IBM's DB2 had a user name limit of 8 in the past, earlier Oracle versions had a limit of 30). Certain Unix versions still have a user name limit of 32.
- other database identifiers, like table / view / index names had typically a size restriction, especially in older databases
- date strings like "1/1/1980" to "12/12/2022" may vary in length between 8 and 10 characters at maximum. Same holds for time strings.
- postal codes should not exceed more than 10 characters internationally (restricted to certain countries, a smaller length will apply)
- international country codes
- car license plate codes in lots of countries.
- IPV4 adresses encoded as decimal strings from "0.0.0.0" to "111.222.333.444". Though it would probably more space efficient to save them just in a 32 bit word, there might be cases where the above notation might be preferred.

But is the saved byte actually worth the hassle it causes? Well, that's definitely case dependend, and today the answer would proabably "no" in most practical cases. But in the 1970s and 80s, memory was a lot more expensive than today, network bandwidth also, and security was not such an issue as it is today. That was the time when `strncpy` was introduced into the C standard lib, by people who had probably several of the above use cases in mind.

***Addendum***: I almost forgot about the #1 use case where I actually had to work with `strncpy`several hundred times : [Embedded SQL (for C)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_SQL). When you declare a host variable of type `char[10]` within the `DECLARE` section, then - in all ESQL dialects I have seen in the past - it can be used for strings of length **up to length 10** (and not just 9 and a trailing `\0`) . The ESQL precompiler makes sure that strings not containing `\0` are processed correctly. And when you are in the situation to pass a standard C string (usually a function parameter) into a `char[10]` vector, then `strncpy` is the right tool for the job.

Of course, ESQL was probably not the reason for having `strncpy` in the C standard lib, but it shows there are way more use cases for this function than one might expect at a first glance, and the C standard lib inventors had probably foreseen several of them.

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that it was perfect to fill some memory structure with 8 bytes for a file name and 3 bytes extension, like this:

```
char nameext[11];
strncpy(&nameext[0], name, 8);
strncpy(&nameext[8], ext, 3);
```

Exactly what DOS needed. I can’t think of anything else where it would be useful.

Against buffer overflows, in my C days I wrote a function mprintf, same arguments as printf, but it would allocate a string for the result using malloc and return that, so you could write

```
char* str1 = …;
char* str2 = …;
int x = …;
char *result = mprintf(“%s,%s,%d”, str1, str2, x);
```

without having to calculate buffer sizes or checking for buffer overflows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm after facts as an answer, not speculation and guesses.

Comment: Related to your `mprintf`, there's also non-standard (also not POSIX) GNU `asprintf`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html

Comment: @hyde: though this answer misses that C came more from the Unix world, according to [Raymond Chen's blog post from 2005](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050107-00/?p=36773), it may not be completely off-track, since in certain old Unix implementations there were similar file name restrictions, and `strncpy` seems to be a suitable string copy function for them.